# MinGW and Boost C++ 1.54.0 warnings

Tags: boost, c++11, warnings

I'm usual to build with consider warning as error. I'm using Boost C++ 1.54.0 with MinGW 4.8.1, in particular I'm using ptree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

This simple program cause the following errors:

```
typedef 'cons_element' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs] line 228, external location: \boost\tuple\detail\tuple_basic.hpp  
typedef 'Str' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs] line 38, external location: \boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_write.hpp
typedef 'Str' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs] line 72, external location: \boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_write.hpp
typedef 'T_must_be_placeholder' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]      line 37, external location: \boost\bind\arg.hpp
```

Is a way to ignore this warnings?

Comment: that's because you have `-Wunused-local-typedefs` compile option just remove that and everything is fine!

Comment: I alawys build with -Wall, and unfortunatly gcc don't allow choose warnings.

Comment: the problem seems to be in boot, try to compile without `-Wall` and see the result! you can also use `-Wno-unused-local-typedefs` I'm not sure if it works or not!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gcc allows ignoring specific warnings since 4.6

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-local-typedefs"
...
...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

there are still some warnings that cannot be turend off this way, but it works for most

or do it like the other mentioned and add -Wno-unused-local-typedefs to the commandline